# social plugin like button comments dialog not displaying

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am embedding a like button in my site using the social plugin. I started with the code generated in like button documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). I'm using standard layout without send or faces. The button itself displays and works fine. However, the the comments dialog does not display.

I found a number of suggestions for making this work, but am unsuccessful so far. The width is 450px. I tried the HTML5, XFBML, and IFrame versions. The IFrame version had the "add comment" link. That dialog displayed but was cutoff. I also used FB.init. Here is my html. I stripped out everything except the like button bits thinking it might be CSS-related but the stripped down version doesn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'appid', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//localhost:8282/myapp/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<!-- <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.espn.com" data-send="false" data-show-faces="false" data-width="450"></div> -->

<fb:like href="http://www.espn.com" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false" />

</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes, it just takes a second pair of eyes. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The comments box only works in a public domain. In other words, it won't display when running the your app on localhost. I believe I did read this on stackoverflow somewhere, but it didn't register.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `"connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"` with `"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"`